# How can I show that $\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{1-xy}dxdy=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ through substitution?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, substitution

I know that the answer can be arrived through integration of geometric series to evaluate $\zeta(2)$, but i was wondering if the result could be attained through a sub?

Comment: Sure, just let $u=x$, $du=dx$ then do that

Comment: Try $u=\dfrac{x+y}{2}$ and $v=\dfrac{y-x}{2}$.